# Windows 10 error : System thread exception not handled

Tags: windows, windows-10, acer-aspire

I am using an Acer Aspire 4710 machine with a 32 bit Intel Core Duo processor 1.86GHz clock speed. The RAM is only 1 GB.

I was using Debian stretch OS on this system. But today I changed to Windows 10. After using for about an hour, the system shut off without any warning. When I rebooted, it shows Windows automatic repair and jumps to a blue screen. It shows the error "System thread exception not handled" and says it needs to restart. This keeps on happening.

Comment: Your system barely meets the [system requirements for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-10-specifications).  Your issue is directly connected to that fact.

Comment: @Ramhound If i change laptop ram to 2.5 gb,then will it work?

Comment: It might help, but your processor barely meets the requirements also, if it runs it will run very poorly.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I saw that the minimum requirement for processor is 1 GHz clock speed. Mine has 1.86 GHz. My system when bought in 2007 came preinstalled with Vista. It was working normally then. Then I changed to windows 7 and then later windows 10. It had some sluggish performance then. It was then I changed to Debian.

Comment: The CPU usage is about 10 to 30 % during most of the time. The RAM memory usage is about 900 MB when idle. Also the laptop can be upgraded to 4 GB RAM. So iam guessing if I upgrade to 2.5 GB then it will work better. Let me check. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After doing some searching online I found a solution. I removed the battery and kept pressing the power button of the machine for about a minute. Then plugged in the power cord and restarted the system. I also connected battery after reboot as soon as possible. Seems it was a static charge issue. After the bios and grub display, the windows started diagnosing and booted normally.

Answer (score 1):

This error check shows that a "system thread generated an exception" that the issuing controller didn't get. To decipher it, you should recognize which exception was generated.

Many people commented, this kind of blue screen issue happens in Windows because of the missing or corrupted drivers or faulty RAM. Accordingly, you need to [reinstall or update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/update-drivers-in-windows-10-ec62f46c-ff14-c91d-eead-d7126dc1f7b6) it.

Regular exception codes:

1. STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT [0x80000002]
2. STATUS_BREAKPOINT[0x80000003]
3. STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION [0xC0000005]

try booting into safe mode and uninstalling the audio driver.. or open the device manager while in safe mode and delete the device.

**if non of these two methods works.**

Somehow, if you are not familiar with this, there is an [article that guides](https://newscutzy.com/windows/fix-system-thread-exception-not-handled/) you step-by-step, how to tackle an SFC Scan, RAM check windows to get rid of this BSOD issue